# Is there a way to reference a specific timespan in Pinescript?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Im only aware of the history referencing operator [], with which one can target certain bars back. But is there any way to reference a fixed timespan?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#var_time

With the time variable, you can test for example

```
if time == timestamp(...)
    // access data from that particular timestamp
```

Comment: Please consider that Pine newbies struggle with the concept of the code being run on every candle (especially historical candles). Your code might work not because it _selects_ some data but because it is run on every candle and your condition might _hit_ the right `time`. However the above is prone to errors as it relies on certain timeframe. If the timestamp is not divisible by the base of the timeframe, the condition will never be true (you will never match 01:03 on an hourly chart). Also it is possible that Tradingview does not have data from the past which you try to reference.